# How to call a method on a React component from another component

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I have a large internal web application written in Laravel and jQuery and am trying to integrate re-usable React components into it (I'm new to React).

I've got a CompanySelector component working - a select element that uses axios to fetch data from the DB and populate the list.
Currently when the user selects an item from the list it calls `window.getCompanyData(this.state.companies[idx].CompanyID)`, which is a jQuery function that loads the data - that works.
I want to replace that with another React component that will handle the loading of it's own data when a company is selected.

company-selector.jsx

```
'use strict';

class CompanySelector extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            error: null,
            isLoaded: false,
            companies: [],
            value: 0,
            index: 0,
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(evt) {
        const idx = evt.target.selectedIndex;
        this.setState({value: evt.target.value, index: idx});
        window.getCompanyData(this.state.companies[idx].CompanyID);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios
            .get('/api/companies')
            .then((result) => {
                this.setState({
                    isLoaded: true,
                    index: 0,
                    companies: result.data.companies.data,
                    value: 0,
                });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.error) {
            return <div>Error: {this.state.error.message}</div>
        }
        if (!this.state.isLoaded) {
            return <div>Loading ...</div>
        } else {
            return (
                <select className="form-select" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                    <option value="0" defaultValue disabled>Select Client</option>
                    {this.state.companies.map((item, idx) => (
                        <option key={idx} value={item.CompanyID}>{item.FullCompanyName}</option>
                    ))}
                </select>
            );
        }
    }

}

const eleCompany = document.getElementById('company-selector');
const rootCompany = ReactDOM.createRoot(eleCompany);
rootCompany.render(<CompanySelector />);
```

My company-data component so far:

```
'use strict';

class CompanyData extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            error: null,
            isLoaded: false,
            info: null,
        };
    }

    getCompanyData(id) {
        alert('fetch data');
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.error) {
            return <div>Error: {this.state.error.message}</div>
        }
        if (!this.state.isLoaded) {
            return <div>Select a company first!</div>
        } else {
            return (
                <ul>
                    <li>{info.PreviousName}</li>
                    <li>{info.Industry}</li>
                    <li>{info.FoundedAt}</li>
                </ul>
            );
        }
    }

}

const eleInfo = document.getElementById('company-data');
const rootInfo = ReactDOM.createRoot(eleInfo);
rootInfo.render(<CompanyData />);
```

How can I call the getCompanyData function of my CompanyData component from my CompanySelector component?

I've searched extensively online but the examples either don't appear to be appropriate to my use case or go completely over my head!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I went with a common parent solution since this was easier for me to wrap my head around:

I created a company-page component:

```
'use strict';

const CompanySelector = 'company-selector';
const CompanyData = 'company-data';

class CompanyPage extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        currentItem: 0
    };

    this.onSelect = this.onSelect.bind(this);
}

onSelect(companyID) {
    this.setState({ currentItem: companyID });
}

render() {
    return <>
        <div class="row">
            <CompanySelector onSelect={this.onSelect} />
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-4">
            <CompanyData fetchData={this.state.currentItem} />
        </div>
    </>
}
}

const elePage = document.getElementById('company-page');
const rootPage = ReactDOM.createRoot(elePage);
rootPage.render(<CompanyPage />);
```

I then adjusted the CompanySelector component by replacing the `window.getCompanyData` line with the following in the handleChange method:

```
    if (this.props.onSelect) {
        this.props.onSelect(evt.target.value);
    }
```

I then went into the CompanyData class and made the following changes:

At the end of the constructor:

```
        this.loadData = this.loadData.bind(this);
}
```

New method for React to signal that something has changed:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevProps.fetchData !== this.props.fetchData) {
        if (this.props.fetchData) {
            this.loadData(this.props.fetchData);
        }
    }
}
```

Load data from the API method (equivalent of window.getCompanyData):

```
loadData(id) {
    //API call using axios excluded for brevity
}
```

In the blade template:

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="company-page" class="company-page">
        <div id="company-selector" class="company-selector"></div>
        <div id="company-data" class="company-data"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If they are independent and you want to reuse that logic, create HOC that injects that function as prop.

If one of them is Parent and the other one is Child, pass the function as prop from Parent to Child

If they are siblings, you can pass the function as prop from their common parent

HOC implementation:

```
const withCompanyData = (Comp) => {
  return class WrapperComponent extends React.Component {
    state = {
      info: null
    }
    getCompanyData = () => {
      // do fetch here and update state
      // and update state
    }
    render() {
      return <Comp getCompanyData={this.getCompanyData} companyState={this.state} />
    }
  }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
const CompanyDataComponent = withCompanyData(CompanyData)
const CompanySelectorComponent = withCompanyData(CompanySelector)
```

Now when you call `<CompanyDataComponent />`, inside your `CompanyData` you can access `getCompanyData` and its `coresponding` state via **props**.

```
props.getCompanyData()
props.companyState
```

With HOC you reuse functionality, but you do not share common state.

If you want to share common state, then you have to pass it as prop from their common Parent

Comment: They're siblings in my case, but am having problems translating examples into working code, what's a HOC?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

Comment: I suggest you take a look at [SWR](https://swr.vercel.app/)

Comment: thanks @Riwen, I'll take a look, it's not the data fetching that's giving me issues though, it's the calling a function from another component. The HOC looks,... advanced.

Comment: It is just a function that creates a component, that wraps the given component and passes props to it. That's it

Comment: I updated my answer with an example for HOC, you can check it

Comment: Thanks @OktayYuzcan, I'll give that a try! If I did want to share common state (companyID), what would a common parent look like?

Comment: If you pass them as props all the way down, then Parent will be a normal component. Or you can use any store, or just a context

Comment: @SteB SWR is not about fetching, per se. Rather, about catching/reusing what you've fetched. Generally, you should not call methods from the outside of react components. Modern react components tend to be just functions, anyway! Try moving the logic outside of components, for example, by using a state management library or SWR.